# Включение подсветки синтаксиса в vim

Tags: c++, linux, vim, syntax

Не понимаю, каким образом мне включить в vim'e подсветку синтаксиса С++. в /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/ лежат файлы с настройками под какждый язык, но я не совсем понимаю, как их подключить. Прошу прощения за крайне глупый вопрос.

Comment: Оно "Turn On or Off Color Syntax Highlighting In vi or vim Editor - nixCraft" https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/turn-on-or-off-color-syntax-highlighting-in-vi-or-vim/

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: `:filetype on | syntax on`

В Vim'е синтаксис и иже с ним реализованы стандартными плагинами на VimScript'е с помощью механизма событий и автокоманд (`:h autocmd.txt`).

Когда Vim считывает файл с диска генерируется событие `BufRead` (`BufNewFile` если такого файла в файловой системе пока не существует). Это событие может быть обработано одной из автокоманд определенных в скрипте `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim`. Загрузка этого скрипта обычно производится специальной командой `:filetype on`. Сам же скрипт по большей части состоит из проверок расширения файла и установок соответствующего значения опции `:h 'filetype'` (очевидно, что расширение файла не всегда совпадает с его типом, например, файл `foobar.h` может иметь тип `c`, либо вообще `cpp`, ну а какой-нибудь `foobar.sh` - это вообще зоопарк и угадайка).

Из вышесказанного следует, что, в принципе, `:filetype on` не обязателен (всегда можно взять и напечатать в командной строке `:set filetype=XXX`, либо `:setf XXX`), но желающие указывать нужный тип файла каждый раз руками находятся редко.

Установка нового значения опции `:h 'filetype'` ведет к автоматической генерации события `FileType`. И, опять же, событие `FileType` может быть перехвачено соответствующими автокомандами из других скриптов. Таких стандартных скриптов есть аж три штуки: `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin.vim` (сорсится по команде `:filetype plugin on`), `$VIMRUNTIME/indent.vim` (команда `:filetype indent on`) и `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syntax.vim` (команда `:syntax on`). Ftplugin отвечает за установку различных буферно-локальных опций, Indent - за определение функции расчета отступа строк, ну а третий, как не трудно догадаться, за определение синтаксических элементов.

Однако на самом деле по событию `FileType` автокоманда из `syntax.vim` всего лишь устанавливает значение еще одной опции - `:h 'syntax'`. И уже изменение опции `:h 'syntax'` (опять!!!) генерирует новое событие `Syntax`. И вот только по событию `Syntax` следующая автокоманда читает значение опции `&syntax` для текущего буфера и подгружает нужный скрипт из подкаталога `syntax` с именем совпадающим со значением этой опции.

Из этого, кстати, следует, что можно переназначить текущий синтаксис командой `:set syntax=XXX`. Однако при следующем событии `FileType` для этого буфера (например, перезагрузка с диска командой `:e`), все слетит на текущий `&filetype`.

Поэтому существует также возможность отвязать `&syntax` от `&filetype` командой `:syntax manual`. Тогда событие `FileType` перехватываться не будет, а вот событие `Syntax` - все еще да. Но в этом случае установку опции `&syntax` всегда нужно будет делать вручную.

И последнее. "Синтаксис" в Vim - это, грубо говоря, набор регулярных выражений (`:h :syn-match` и все-все-все), который меняется от буфера к буферу. Конкретные же цвета должны определяться глобально с помощью так называемых "цветовых схем" (на самом деле "схема" - это все тот же VimScript просто состоящий в основном из команд `:h :highlight`). Поэтому полученный результат будет зависеть и от файла синтаксиса, и от цветовой схемы, и от способности терминала эти самые цвета воспроизвести.